# how stick out a menu when clicking on a menu

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a type of menu created in JSF.

```js
    <p:menubar styleClass="menuPrincipal" id="menuBar" > 
    <p:menuitem value="Inicio" url="/Inicio.xhtml" style="text-decoration:none"   icon="ui-icon-home" id="inicio" /> 
    <p:menuitem value="Agregar Excepciones" id="agregarExcepcion" url="/ExcepcionNuevo.xhtml" style="text-decoration:none" rendered='#{excepcionPendienteView.usuarioActual.tipoSolicitante eq "Administrador"}' /> 
</p:menubar>
```

---

---

I want that when you click on a menu,  highlight the option me where I am working.

if I click on "Inicio" highlighting my menuItem Inicio, and if i click on "Agregar" highlighting  my menuItem "Agregar Excepciones". Try to do it with Js, but I did not make the function (). Try to do it with ajax but the example I found , did it with a dataTable using blockUit.

Comment: It's impossible to understand what you mean.

Comment: Please improve the question. Include what is that you want to achieve and what is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: What I want is can marck active menuitem using js, but the page refresh when clicking on menu.

Comment: Please, post your HTML also.

Comment: I am working with JSF.  Here this code  .....<p:menubar styleClass="menuPrincipal" id="menuBar" >
            <p:menuitem value="Inicio" url="/Inicio.xhtml" style="text-decoration:none" icon="ui-icon-home" />
            <p:menuitem value="Agregar Excepciones"  url="/ExcepcionNuevo.xhtml" style="text-decoration:none" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" rendered='#{excepcionPendienteView.usuarioActual.tipoSolicitante eq "Administrador"}'  />
 </p:menubar>

Comment: Please update your question with more details and proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for this tag ([here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/menuitem.html)), you'll see that:

```
url => Url to be navigated when menuitem is clicked.
```

That's why your page reloads when you click an item. Probably removing this attribute will stop the reload action from happening.

Then you'll probably want to use `onclick`, or `action` to load the page (and mark the menu item). Alternatively, if you work with *AJAX*, you can use `onstart`, `oncomplete` and `onsuccess`.

Comment: but as work, using ajax on menu  or page .xhtml

Comment: You'll need to do a search and read material to learn. You can see some showcases ( http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf ). Basically, you can modify specific parts of the page without reloading it all.

Comment: but as you would on a menu, this example function for dataTable.also BlockUit not working with menuItem